# Magento1- How to add custom field in custom module form like a tier price in product

Tags: magento-1.9

Here I have got this error, when add this file.. What i have to do???

**Fatal error:**

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Sharesoft_Donations_Block_Adminhtml_Donations_Edit_Tab_Amount' not found in D:\xampp71\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php:491
```

**Stack trace:**

```
#0 D:\xampp71\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('Sharesoft_Donat...', Array) 

#1 D:\xampp71\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\Sharesoft\Donations\Block\Adminhtml\Donations\Edit\Tabs.php(24): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('donations/admin...') 

#2 D:\xampp71\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(922): Sharesoft_Donations_Block_Adminhtml_Donations_Edit_Tabs->_beforeToHtml() 

#3 D:\xampp71\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() 

#4 D:\xampp71\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml() 

#5 D:\xampp71\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml() 

#6 D:\xampp71\htdocs\magento\app\co in D:\xampp71\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 491
```